Group action induces smooth embedding from twisted product with isotropy type
Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $G$ be a smooth Lie group acting properly on $M$. Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ and $\mathrm{N}(H)$ its normalizer. Define $I(H) = \{x \mid G_x = H\}$ to be set of points with isotropy exactly $H$. How can I show that the multiplication map $G \times I(H) \to M$ descends to a smooth embedding $G/H \times_{\mathrm{N}(H)/H} I(H) \to M$?
The topological version of this problem is clear enough to me, so my question is basically about showing that the map we get is an immersion. I have seen this fact stated in a few places but no rigorous proof except a comment that it follows from the slice/tube theorem, so I'm interested in a more in-depth explanation.
If we look at the proof of the Tube theorem 2.4.1 in Duistermaat and Kolk's book we find that they make use of conditions (i) and (ii) of their slice definition to establish surjectivity of the differential, and then use a dimension argument to establish injectivity. Maybe there is an analogous way to proceed here?

This is chapter 2.6 (pages 107 to 111) and especially Theorem 2.6.7 (iv) on page 110 in J.J. Duistermaat and J. A. C. Kolk, Lie Groups.

I'm actually familiar with this book. Unfortunately the proof only mentions that it "follows from the tube theorem." I could not quite understand how... Specifically it only states "the equivalence follows as in the proof of the Tube theorem 2.4.1." Other sources just reference this book or say that it follows from the tube theorem similarly. Do you think you could explain how it follows?

Also 2.6.7 is concerned with what I know to be "normal isotropy type." Although I think my case should follow if I can understand the proof (iv) (and maybe (i)). However in both of these places the authors just state that it follows from the tube theorem without explaining how it is applied. Maybe I am missing something.

@SarahBrooks Do you no understand why the map is smooth or how the diffeomorphism is defined?

Well, it should be smooth. But to show it is a diffeomorphism we need to understand what the differential does no? If we look at the proof of 2.4.1 we make use of the condition that the tangent space of the orbit and the slice sum to the entire space at each point. It's not clear to me how to develop an analogous result here.

@SarahBrooks So, basically your problem is to understand why the bijective smooth map is a diffeomorphism?

Yes, as stated in my question, the topological part (definedness, that we get a topological embedding) is clear to me. It's specifically about showing that the map is an immersion. And that I've seen that it follows from the tube/slice theorem, but I am not sure of the precise details. I would be happy to see some more details about how the tube theorem is applied.
